# Splitting Strings and Generating Frequency Tables in R

Tags: r, string, split, frequency

I have a column of firm names in an **R** dataframe that goes something like this:

```
"ABC Industries"  
"ABC Enterprises"  
"123 and 456 Corporation"  
"XYZ Company"
```

And so on.  I'm trying to generate frequency tables of every word that appears in this column, so for example, something like this:

```
Industries   10  
Corporation  31  
Enterprise   40  
ABC          30  
XYZ          40
```

I'm relatively new to **R**, so I was wondering of a good way to approach this.  Should I be splitting the strings and placing every distinct word into a new column?  Is there a way to split up a multi-word row into multiple rows with one word?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wanted to, you could do it in a one-liner:

```
R> text <- c("ABC Industries", "ABC Enterprises", 
+            "123 and 456 Corporation", "XYZ Company")
R> table(do.call(c, lapply(text, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))))

        123         456         ABC         and     Company 
          1           1           2           1           1 
Corporation Enterprises  Industries         XYZ 
          1           1           1           1 
R>
```

Here I use `strsplit()` to break each entry intro components; this returns a list (within a list).  I use `do.call()` so simply concatenate all result lists into one vector, which `table()` summarises.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I've been fiddling with the original code and I find that I get the same results with:

table(unlist(strsplit(text, " ")))

What purpose do lapply() and do.call() serve?

Answer (score 6):

Here is another one-liner. It uses `paste()` to combine all of the column entries into a single long text string, which it then splits apart and tabulates:

```
text <- c("ABC Industries", "ABC Enterprises", 
         "123 and 456 Corporation", "XYZ Company")

table(strsplit(paste(text, collapse=" "), " "))
```

Comment: +1 Great, I would only add split="\\s{1,}" to make it more robust

Comment: @WojciechSobala Yep -- I had the same thought, and it probably is better/closer to what the OP wants. `split = "\\s+"` or `split = "[[:space:]]+"` are two other exactly equivalent options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `tidytext` and `dplyr`:

```r
set.seed(42)

text <- c("ABC Industries", "ABC Enterprises", 
       "123 and 456 Corporation", "XYZ Company")

data <- data.frame(category = sample(text, 100, replace = TRUE),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, category) %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  count()

#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#> # Groups:   word [9]
#>          word     n
#>         <chr> <int>
#> 1         123    29
#> 2         456    29
#> 3         abc    45
#> 4         and    29
#> 5     company    26
#> 6 corporation    29
#> 7 enterprises    21
#> 8  industries    24
#> 9         xyz    26
```